# How to response.sendRedirect to a pop-up window?

Tags: jsp, servlets, popup, alert, response.redirect

On our product pages, we have a form that sends data to a servlet that adds the product to the cart and then redirects to either a more products page or to the shopping cart page:

```
      if (productAddOn.equals("1")) {
           response.sendRedirect("/show-more-products.jsp");
      }
      else  {
           response.sendRedirect("/shopping-cart.jsp");
      }
```

What we would like to do is, after customer adds a product to cart, have the servlet sendRedirect back to the original product page and initiate a pop-up/alert advising "Product A has been added to Cart", etc.

Is it possible to initiate a pop-up/alert in the above manner?

Thanks for the suggestions and feedback.

Best,
MB

Comment: yes you can do that simply add a message inside session using [setAttribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) and then get in your page where you need to redirect using `el` i.e `<p>${attributenamesetinseesion}</p>` .Also check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) out for styling your message.

Comment: Thanks Swati for the fast response. Looks like I need to brush up on my EL skill set!